# Use list comprehension to print out a list with words of length 4

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a list comprehension that uses List1 to create a list of words of length 4.

```
 List1 = ['jacob','batman','mozarella']


wordList = [words for i in range(1)]
print(wordList)
```

This prints out the wordList however with words of length higher than 4
I am looking for this program to print out instead:

```
['jaco','batm','moza']
```

which are the same words in List1 but with length 4

I tried this and it didn't work

```
wordList = [[len(4)] words for i in range(1)]
```

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use this list comp

```
>>> List1 = ['jacob','batman','mozarella']
>>> [i[:4] for i in List1]
['jaco', 'batm', 'moza']
```

Ref:

- `i[:4]` is a slice of the string of first 4 characters

Other ways to do it (All have their own disadvantages)

- `[re.sub(r'(?<=^.{4}).*', '', i) for i in List1]`
- `[re.match(r'.{4}', i).group() for i in List1]`
- `[''.join(i[j] for j in range(4)) for i in List1]`
- `[i.replace(i[4:],'') for i in List1]` ----- Fails in case of `moinmoin` or `bongbong`

[Credit - Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610568/use-list-comprehension-to-print-out-a-list-with-words-of-length-4/28610585?noredirect=1#comment45525565_28610585)

Comment: another way `[i.replace(i[4:],'') for i in List1]` or `[re.sub(r'(?<=^.{4}).*', '', i) for i in List1]` or `[re.match(r'.{4}',  i).group() for i in List1]`

Answer (score 4):

1. `len()` function return the length of string in your case. So list compression with len function will give the list of all item lenght.

e.g.

```
>>> List1 = ['jacob','batman','mozarella']
>>> [len(i) for i in List1]
[5, 6, 9]
>>>
```

2. Use `slice()` list method to get substring from the string. [more info](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)

e.g.

```
>>> a = "abcdef"
>>> a[:4]
'abcd'

>>> [i[:4] for i in List1]
['jaco', 'batm', 'moza']
```

---

Python beginner

1. Define `List1`.
2. Define empty `List2`
3. Use `for` loop to iterate every item from the `List1`
4. Use list `append()` method to add item into list with `slice()` method.
5. Use print to see result.

sample code:

```
>>> List1 = ['jacob','batman','mozarella']
>>> List2 = []
>>> for i in List1:
...     List2.append(i[:4])
... 
>>> print List2
['jaco', 'batm', 'moza']
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

One more way, now using map function:

```
List1 = ['jacob','batman','mozarella']
List2 = map(lambda x: x[:4], List1)
```